# How to update header login link using ajax Magento 2

Tags: ajax, magento2.1.0, section

I have created **sections.xml** as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="customer/ajax/login">
        <section name="header"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

But I have found in response **"section source is not supported"**.

[image]

I want to update highlighted part in above image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got solution using below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">    
    <action name="customer/ajax/login">
        <section name="customer"/>
    </action>
    <action name="customer/ajax/login">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```